# combining specific values in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my list

```
['INQ/DATA', 'ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN', 'GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT', 'TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT', 'FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP', 'FILE', '0', 'REPORT', 'FILE', '0']
```

I want the answer set like below...

```
['INQ/DATA ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP FILE', '0', 'REPORT 
FILE', '0']
```

I am looking for short program instead of too much loop
I tried for loop

```
           for i in range(len(ar2)-2):

               if i < len(ar2)-4 :
                   if len(ar2[i])>1 and len(ar2[i+1]) > 1:
                      #print ar2[i]+' '+ar2[i+1]
                      fll.append(ar2[i]+' '+ar2[i+1])
                      del ar2[i+1]
                   else:

                       fll.append(ar2[i])
               else:
                    fll.append(ar2[i])
```

please advise....
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the list items into a string literal using `.join` then `split` the string with `re` into a list of items using the numbers.

Build the final list by using a list comprehension on the splitted items to `strip` and `filter` whitespace characters:

```
import re

lst = ['INQ/DATA', 'ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN', 'GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT', 'TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT', 'FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP', 'FILE', '0', 'REPORT', 'FILE', '0']
s = " ".join(lst)

p = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
result = [i.strip() for i in p.split(s) if i != '']
# ['INQ/DATA ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP FILE', '0', 'REPORT FILE', '0']
```

Comment: one more question..... I have test field this ..........pp ="DEFAULT SECURITY NO      CUSTOMER        C 00     LOANS           L 00     INQUIRY         I 00     NAME/ADDRESS    5 00
                         BACKDATE 1-7    E 00     BACKDATE 8-30   F 00     BACKDATE > 30   G 00
ACCESS ALL FUNC. NO

*** FLOOR LIMITS ***
                  0"  ......I want result like this ...['DEFAULT SECURITY','NO','CUSTOMER','C','LOAN','L','INQUIRY','I','NAME/ADDRESS','5','BACKDATE 1-7','E','BACKDATE 8-30','F','BACKDATE > 30','G','FLOOR LIMITS','0']

Comment: You can start with `pp.replace('*', '').split()`. Then modify by merging items from `.split`

Answer (score 0):

Let [*itertools.groupby*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) do it for you, passing `str.isdigit` as the key:

```
l =  ['INQ/DATA', 'ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN', 'GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT', 'TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT', 'FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP', 'FILE', '0', 'REPORT', 'FILE', '0']

from itertools import groupby

new = [" ".join(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=str.isdigit)]
```

Output:

```
In [4]: from itertools import groupby

In [5]: [" ".join(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=str.isdigit)]
Out[5]:  ['INQ/DATA ENTRY', '1', 'MONETARY', '0', 'TRAN GRID', '0', 'BCR', '0', 'ENVIRONMENT TBL', '0', 'PRODUCT FILE', '0', 'STOP/HOLD', '1', 'QUERY', '0', 'LOOKUP FILE', '0', 'REPORT FILE', '0']
```

To work for negative numbers or floats you can use a helper function:

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print([" ".join(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=f)])
```